# Show that $f(f(x)) = x, g(g(x)) = x$ does not imply $f(g(x)) = g(f(x)).$

Tags: functions, logic

Premise: $f(f(x)) = x, g(g(x)) = x$

Prove that: 
$f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ is not true.

Comment: You just need to construct a counter-example. Can you pick a pair $f,g$ to satisfy the premise?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? You've asked multiple questions now without showing any work; we're happy to help with homework, but we won't just do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

Let the domain for both function be $\mathbb{R}^2$,

$$f(p,q)=(q,p)$$

$$g(p,q)=(p,-q)$$

$$f(g((p,q))=f(p,-q)=(-q,p)$$

$$g(f(p,q))=g(q,p)=(q,-p)$$

Answer (score 1):

One simple example would be $f(x)=1-x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 1):

On a real line (w/o zero) consider the family of functions of the form $$F(a;x)=\frac{a}{x}.$$ For instance, let $f(x)=\dfrac{2}{x}$ and  $g(x)=\dfrac{3}{x}$.